# Building OpenCV & OpenCV Extra Modules For Android From Source

Tags: android, opencv, cmake, cmake-gui, opencv-contrib

I used the link below
https://zami0xzami.wordpress.com/2016/03/17/building-opencv-for-android-from-source/#comment-81

I succeeded build for armeabi-v7a abi i want build for arm64-v8a and do not see in Android Abi list
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRNkH.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

add entry to cmake gui

ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN_NAME : aarch64-linux-android-4.9